# Jquery comparing 2 items

Tags: jquery, magento

I've scoured this site looking for an answer to this question I know I'm going to get reamed for being asked already.  Unfortunately none of the answers have worked for me.  I have a Magento site that populates a products image and prices on a CMS page.  I can pull in everything just fine.  The issue I am having is with the prices.  Since it's pulling is both sale price and regular price, even if a product isn't on sale it will generate two prices.  My question is how do I run a check with jquery and eliminate the sale price if its the same as the regular price?

My Markup/PHP:

```
<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getData('product_id')); ?>
<div class="priceContainer">
<p id="regularPrice" class="price regular"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getPrice()); ?></p>


<p id="salePrice" class="price sale"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getFinalPrice(), true, false); ?></p>
```

my Jquery:

```
<script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
var regPrice = $j('#regularPrice');
var salePrice = $j('#salePrice');
if (salePrice[0] === regPrice[0]) {
    $j('#salePrice').css('display', 'none');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is tht you are comparing the JQuery object. Try comparing like this:

`$(v).text() === salePrice.eq(k).text()`

The explanation is that in your code you are comparing JQuery objects which have more information than the inner text, which is the price.

So, you have to get the text from the JQuery objects. You can do that invoking the `.text()` method.

**Edit:**
Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ivan0013/rpgw4zmn/) to see an example working in a loop.

**WARNING:** you should not use the same id more than once. Instead of that you should use a class

Comment: My issue now is that there are 4 products on this page that are populated.  Theis script works however it only is applying to the first product the other 3 have repeated prices.

Comment: You need a loop for that. I will edit the answer in a few minutes to solve that

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work.  Im trying to utilize the .each but it's not working either

Comment: @user1568811 I create a fiddle where it is working. Check the answer.

Comment: Definitely working on fiddle but for some reason it only goes through the first item on the rendered page.  The other three are not affected.  Not sure if this has anything to do with Magento serving up the prices...probably not.  I really appreciate the effort thank you very much.  I'm going to keep digging.

Comment: OK had a major DERP moment.  You code works beautiful now.  I was selecting to the prices by ID not the class.  Once I switched to class everything worked like a charm.  Again YOU THE MAN Ivan!!!!!